# Pass multiple arguments to spyne soap method separately

Tags: django, web-services, soap, wsdl, spyne

I want to use Spyne to create a web-service in Django with SOAP inputs and outputs. The problem is spyne generates the WSDL file so that a client needs to pass all the arguments as one object.

Consider [Sypne's own hello world example](http://spyne.io/#inprot=Soap11&outprot=Soap11&s=rpc&tpt=DjangoApplication&validator=true), when I want to call the `say_hello` method for example from a C# client, input should be an object which has `name` and `times` attributes:

```
client.say_hello(SayHelloInputInstace);
```

but I want to call by passing a `name` and `times` separately:

```
client.say_hello('john', 5);
```

Is it possible to create a Spyne web-service method that can be called RPC-like by passing each argument separately?

Comment: This is not a Spyne question, but a Suds question. You can try _body_tyle='bare' but that may or may not be what you need.

Comment: @BurakArslan thanks! as I want to use spyne, I used spyne tag according to spyne's suggestion [here](http://spyne.io/docs/2.11/#getting-support)